# Jenkins build result of shell script calling java program

Tags: java, bash, jenkins

I want my Jenkins build to fail if a shell script which calls a java program fails.

The java program catches any exception and exits with **-1**

```
catch (Throwable e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

The **myscript.sh** bash script calls the java program like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# exit immediately if any command fails
set -e

java MyJavaProgram

exit 0
```

Jenkins is just using a **Execute shell** build step with command:

```
cd /home/jenkins/deployments/Scripts
sh myscript.sh
```

However in my Jenkins console log, I can see an exception message and stacktrace, but the overall jenkins build is shown as **Finished: SUCCESS**

Am I missing anything?

Comment: The `set -e` should mean that it exits the script before it gets to the last line of `exit 0` - AFAIK.

Comment: But doesn't the `set -e` return _the exit status code of the command that failed_ so the `exit 0` is not executed in this case? The `exit 0` is just for green path when the the java program is successful.

Comment: Status codes aren't usually negative, what happens if you `exit(1)` instead?

Comment: Please check the docu of Jenkins sh command. It looks like it just return the stdout of the shell script by default. Handling of return status is not done by default.

Comment: @Mar-Z Good point, it's `status = sh(script: './myscript.sh', returnStatus: true)` to get the exit status.

Comment: @Mar-Z from the Jenkins documentation: _By default, the shell will be invoked with the "-ex" option. So all of the commands are printed before being executed, and the build is considered a failure if any of the commands exits with a non-zero exit code_   From this I would assume the build should fail, if the set -e triggers a non-zero exit code, when my java program returns **-1**.

Comment: @BenjaminW. That's for a _Pipeline_ project, I'm just running the **Execute shell** build step of a _Freestyle_ project jenkins job.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a misconfiguration. Jenkins  meets the standard:

- 0 as exit code : means success
- non zero exit code : means error

I tried and jenkins (latest 2023 version: 2.426.1) works as expected. Replicate this in a new job

### Free style : Build step

```
cd /tmp/sandbox/
cat /tmp/sandbox/Demo.java
sh /tmp/sandbox/myscript.sh
```

Full job configuration here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wjrx.png

### Job ends with Success in case of 0 as exit code

```
public class Demo {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Im the java program");
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

With shell:

[image]

With jenkins

[image]

### Job ends with Failure in case of non zero as exit code

```
public class Demo {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Im the java program");
    System.exit(-1);
  }
}
```

With shell:

[image]

With jenkins

[image: Returns a non zero with 1 instead -1]